# Noise and vibrations in car (VW GTI 2011)

Tags: tires, noise, vibration

I have been having lots of noise and vibrations at high speed.
I took to the dealer (VW) and was told it was because of flat spots on my tires. Its a front wheel drive.

My threads are in pretty good condition. They can easily go 10k miles more.

Does the flat spots create any problems elsewhere in the vehicle? Should I replace the tires ASAP?

Also could there be other reasons why this noise and vibrations happen?

Adding a video so everyone will have better idea..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjMFzi_xmPk

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possible things which could cause vibrations:

1. When breaking hard, your discs could take up some heat and get
   warped, great article could be [found
   here](http://www.mossmotors.com/SiteGraphics/Pages/brake_discs.html).
2. Bad geometry could cause vibrations + uneven tyre wear (flat spots
   maybe?), see [related
   article](http://ebcbrakes.com/articles/steering-wheel-vibration/).
3. Check wheel balancing, [article
   here](https://www.bigotires.com/librarydetail/Tire-Balancing---Why-Does-it-Matter).

I would recommend to check these first, there are couple more issues but these are the most common, which could possibly fix your problem.

Boris

Comment: Thanks. I do notice that between 15-20mph (speeding up or down), the vibrations are the most. May be point 2 applies. I don't think there is vibrations while breaking. I had wheel rotation a couple month back. I don't know if it included balancing. But this advice certainly helped.

Comment: Also, can wheel alignment have a case in this.

Comment: Geometry=wheel alignment, yop this could be it, going through potholes/bumps could scatter wheel alignment.

Comment: Thanks, Please check out the video link I attached to the ques.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly discs do not warp.Pads contain metal that deposit on rotor so when measured 
in a number of places it is assumed the disc is warped.Check balance weights on rim have
not fallen off.Jack up front wheels one at a time;grasp tyre each side of centre and pull to and away from you.Any noise or movement may indicate that tension on bearings is incorrect

Comment: Thanks, Please check out the video link I attached to the ques.